# What type of "it" is used in "It had been agreed…"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

What type of "it" is used in this sentence:

> It had been agreed that they should all meet in the big barn as soon as Mr. Jones was safely out of the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distinguish it-cleft and extraposition? 'It was Ben that found it' v 'It was clear that Ben found it'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597679/how-to-distinguish-it-cleft-and-extraposition-it-was-ben-that-found-it-v-it)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't follow you. An _it_-cleft has its backgrounded element expressed in a relative clause, but there is no relative clause in the OP's example. I'd say that it's an extraposition construction. I agree that "it" is a dummy element.

Comment: @Vanessa The pronoun "it" is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. Your example is an extraposition construction, where the extraposed element ("that they should all meet ...")  doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the verb phrase.

Comment: PaulQ at [Word Reference Forums]() distinguishes the 'it' in extrapositions (which BillJ is quite right is what is occurring here): '[In] the example "It is raining" – "It" is a dummy subject because it has no referent. [But in]
"It is difficult to understand you." - "it is the preparatory "it" as it has a [later] referent.' [_To understand you_ is what is difficult.]

Comment: @laurel  How did this linguistics question get sent to ELL? What makes anyone think the OP is not a native speaker? This is not acceptable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we put 'it' beginning of sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131640/why-we-put-it-beginning-of-sentences)

Comment: @Astralbee We don't need a link. It's obvious that in Extraposition the "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

Comment: @BillJ Not sure what you mean by "*we don't need a link*". Are you objecting to the link to a previous question? Because SE puts that in automatically when one votes to close on the basis of a duplicate. I just cast my vote. If you have an issue with the link being posted  you'd have to take that up with SE. Perhaps make a post in meta?